# How does IDA provide function names to dynamic calls?

Tags: ida

I'm trying to compare a binary (a basic hello world exe compiled with MinGW) within Immunity Debugger and IDA. In Immunity I notice a call to EAX which points to `004019c0`.

[image: immunity eax]

Looking in IDA I notice this call is identified as `___dyn_tls_init_callback`. I want to better understand how IDA gets this name and applies to this address.

[image: ida eax named]

If I follow the function in IDA via xrefs I see a reference to the code with a label provided by IDA but I'm unsure where this name comes from. How can I figure out how IDA got this name? I'd like to understand further so I can do the work myself in Immunity.

[image: ida xref followed]

Comment: In short, IDA is disassembler + decompiler which Immunity isn't. That function is a part of C runtime and it's an indirect call.